# Disable checks for non-existent styles

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an email template builder in React and I need to be able to have things like `Margin` (with a capital M) in the style tags of rendered elements. This is for compatibility reasons with older email clients like Outlook.

Writing this:

```
<table
    cellPadding="0"
    cellSpacing="0"
    style={{
        margin: '0 auto',
        Margin: '0 auto',
    }}
>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Totally ignores the second, uppercase `Margin` on render. How can I get the second `Margin` to be applied instead of ignored?

Comment: Not familiar with ReactJS, but I do know that CSS property declarations are separated with a semi-colon `;`. Is your use of a comma `,` ReactJS syntax?

Comment: Yes it is; React sees CSS styles as a Javascript object so that it can parse them or inject variable data into them.

Comment: I would apply a `className` instead, have a look at `css-loader`.

Comment: @MarioTacke no can do, it has to be inline for email compatibility purposes. Otherwise this would of course be much simpler.

Comment: You could [Dangerously Set innerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to get this output. All in all a hacky way of doing this though.

Comment: @MarioTacke yeah, that's going to be my fallback method; I'm hoping someone knows a less-hacky way though. Feel free to propose it as an answer though, if only for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion, you can always make use of [Dangerously Set innerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to get your desired, custom, output.

React [inline styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) do not support custom property names at this time.